# PHP UPLOAD - upload files that contain php snippets (*.tpl extensions)

Tags: php, upload

i'm trying to upload a `.tpl`  file that contain php and html tags , via PHP to do some process on it, but when i start uploading and i want to show uploaded file contents , i see that php tags was commecnted , what is my problem ! i do lots of search but no results.

Comment: How are you showing the file contents?

Comment: humm m i use `file_get_contents` function and print contents on a div

Comment: PHP tags commented means?

Comment: yes ! all php tags was commented when i want to open the uploaded file.

Comment: Post the file that you get after retrieving from server. How can comment get added automatically? Post both the files before uploading and after uploading

Comment: i know , but my tpl file before uploading have not any php tag commented , and when i upload it and read the tmp file i see the php tags was commended :(